# Execute POST off main thread

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I execute a post such as below off the main thread?

```
  var post:String = "fname=\(addy)&lname=\(fff)&time=\(ff)&action=\(sd_asds)&actionid=add&content=\(d)".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Is it possible that running the post on the main thread would cause a memory warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send a POST request you can use the NSURLConnection class which has a method to send the request `asyncrhonously` meaning it will execute "off the main thread".

Example:

```
 var post:String = "fname=\(addy)&lname=\(fff)&time=\(ff)&action=\(sd_asds)&actionid=add&content=\(d)".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
 var postURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: post)

let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:postURL)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ response, data, error in 
//your code here
 })
```

**Documentation:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Comment: Check the update, it will be the HTTP request you want to send.

Comment: is this the same thing as what you are suggesting?  var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

Comment: I am not sure of that method but it looks like you are looking for the completion handler. Check the update for a complete call which also has a completion handler which you can enter your code upon completion of the request and check the response or error if there is one.

Comment: Did you forget to close the completion handler addition?

Comment: No its closed at the end `})`

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Does a completion handler help with memory management?

Comment: A completion handler is used to execute code when your request completes. Since the request is asynchronous it executes on a separate thread and therefore you do not know when it finishes, the completion handler is called once it finishes so you can update variables or whatever you may need. Otherwise you may try to use the results before it actually finishes.